# picture inside a grid view according to some value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, eval

I got a field status has three value : 
0 pendding 
1 accept
2 refuse

i want to add it on grid view but with image instead of numbers :

```
if 0  select.png
if 1  ok.png
if 2  no.png
```

i tried this code but didnt see the picture :

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='~/img/<%# (Eval("id") == "1") ? "ok.png" : "" ; %>'></asp:Image>
```

what should i do ?? and how to add three condition ?

Comment: give me an error : The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two different way:-

**1st Way:--**
Use the TemplateColumn instead of bound column, and include `<asp:image>` control in it. And then  add the  OnRowDataBound event to Grid.

Then attach your Images, based on your if statement.

Sample Code under `GridView_RowDataBound` event

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       Image i = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("image");
       //include your if statement here, and set ImageUrl
       i.ImageUrl = "select.png";
    }
```

**2nd Way**
Add ImageField in GridView under Template Column

```
<asp:Image HeaderText='Status' 
        ImageUrl='<%# ImageDisplay(Eval("Status").ToString()) %>' />
```

and You'd then need a method like the following in your codebehind:

```
protected string ImageDisplay(string status)
{
     ///write you if condition and return image path url
      //return "~\select.png";
}
```

Comment: i make a little changing of your work : 
ImageUrl='<%# ImageDisplay(Eval("status").ToString()) %>'
======
protected string ImageDisplay(String status)

thx its work now

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change your image name to '0.png', '1.png' and '2.png' and so on, so it is easy for you to bind the value, just like

```
ImageUrl='~/img/<%# (Eval("id") + ".png")
```

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='../img/<%#Eval("status") %>.png'></asp:Image>

i try this it didnt work 

but when you write : 
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='../img/0.png'></asp:Image>
it works

Comment: You need to check what your imageUrl is, i mean check the value in browser